# useState returning a 172 object array 172 times instead of the single object with 172 fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, papaparse

So I am using React to pull Covid-19 data from a CSV using papaparse. I then filter this array to only show results from today. I am using a functional react component like so:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Papa from 'papaparse'
import dataJSON from './data/CovidLocations.json'
import {Tooltip, Circle } from "react-leaflet";

const DashBoard = (props) => {
    const [data, setDataArr] = useState([]);
    const [dailyResults, setDailyResults] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {    
        getData()
    }, [dailyResults]); 

    const getData = () => {
        Papa.parse("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tomwhite/covid-19-uk-data/master/data/covid-19-cases-uk.csv", {
            download: true,
            header: true,
            complete: (results) => {
                var data = results.data
                setDataArr(data)
                setData(data)
            }
        });
    }

    const setData = (data) => {
        let merged = [];
        let result = [];

        for(let i=0; i< data.length; i++) {
            merged.push({
             ...data[i], 
             ...(dataJSON.find((itmInner) => itmInner.Location === data[i].Area))}
            );  
        }

        result = merged.filter(obj => {
            return obj.Date === "2020-04-02"
        });

        let output = result.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).includes("Latitude"));

        setDailyResults(output)
        console.log(dailyResults)

    }


        return(
            <div>
            {dailyResults &&
            dailyResults.map(({Location, Latitude, Longitude, TotalCases}, i) => (
            <Circle
                key={`markers-${i}`}
                center={[Latitude, Longitude]}
                radius={35 * TotalCases}
                fillColor="red"
                color="black"
                weight="0.5"
            >
                <Tooltip>
                <span>
                    <b>Location</b>: {Location}
                    <br />
                    <b>Total Cases</b>: {TotalCases}
                </span>
                </Tooltip>
            </Circle>
            ))}
            </div>
        )

}

export default DashBoard;
```

At line 46 here `console.log(dailyResults)` it returns the object correctly, mapped with the other json object, but it then iterates through the object 172 times (the same number of array values). What I need is this code to execute, map the array from the CSV, add the latlngs (all which works fine) but then in the return statement I need the array of 172 to not keep looping so It can be passed into `react-leaflet` as an object to create map markers. It seems like a simple issue, I just do not know how to implement it.

dataJSON format:

```
  {
    "Location": "Barking and Dagenham",
    "Latitude": 53.546299,
    "Longitude": -1.46786
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dailyResults` is changing multiple times because you are looping over a lot of data, so probably you are requesting also multiples times csv data then you should probably take an infinite loop and your browser stack as you change also `output` variable as many times as you are looping over `data` variable.

So what I understand you want to achieve is to extract the `Location`, `Latitude` and Longitude from the `dataJSON` and also extract the `TotalCases` from the csv by comparing `Area` with `Location`. If that is the case you can do it in a simple way:

After parsing the data from the csv, loop over `dataJSON` and `data` like this using a constant variable to push an object with the above mentioned data you want to include:

```
  let dailyResults = [];

  data.find((csv) => {
    dataJSON.forEach((json) => {
      if (csv.Area === json.Location) {
        dailyResults.push({
          Location: json.Location,
          Latitude: json.Latitude,
          Longitude: json.Longitude,
          TotalCases: csv.TotalCases,
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

and remove `dailyResults` from dependency array:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/plot-coronavirus-incidents-in-uk-using-react-leaflet-9upuz)